# Virtual laser pointer when using Office Remote and a Surface Pro 3 goes to the wrong position

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, microsoft-powerpoint, remote, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I have to do presentations quite often and I recently noticed the Office Remote App (I'm using the Windows Phone 8.1 version in case that matters). So before actually doing the presentation in front of everyone, I've tried out the app and one of the nice features is the virtual laser pointer: you can touch the slide on your screen and the virtual laser pointer will display there.

So this is how it should work when I connect an external screen/projector. However, when I connect an external display the laser pointer won't go where I'm touching the screen: it will stay in maybe a 70%*70% box (from top left) so I can't point where I want. I assumed it would be because a problem of matching resolution between the two screens so I tried changing the resolution so both are the same, restarting PowerPoint and the App several times and I still have the problem. I also tried disabling the screen on the Surface and only displaying on the external but I still have the same problem.

I also tried on a different computer (HpProBook) and it works fine even if both screens have different resolutions. This computer is running Windows 7 (and Windows 8.1 on the Surface). However, it is much heavier and can't last as long on the battery so I would rather bring my Surface for presentations.

My guess would be that it comes from the fake half definition the surface gives some applications so they don't look too small. However, I have no idea how I can fix this.

Comment: What fake resolution? I have the device and never encountered anything like that

Comment: A Surface Pro3 has a 2160x1440 screen. However, most applications see only half that. This allows the applications that aren't made to support the screen to show up with an appropriate size. As for an example of the fake resolution: opening a window with the SDL opens a window twice as large (in pixels) that what you would expect it to be without the scaling.